# Azure function retrieve row from Azure table storage

Tags: c#, azure, function, azure-storage

trying to retrieve all rows from table storage my code is like this like in the documentation

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.Table;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.Linq;

public class TableStorage
{
    public class MyPoco : TableEntity
    {
        public string Text { get; set; }
        public object PartitionKey { get; internal set; }
        public object RowKey { get; internal set; }
    }

    [FunctionName("TableInput")]
    public static void TableInput(
        [QueueTrigger("table-items")] string input,
        [Table("MyTable")] IQueryable<MyPoco> pocos,
        ILogger log)
    {
        foreach (MyPoco poco in pocos)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"PK={poco.PartitionKey}, RK={poco.RowKey}, Text={poco.Text}");
        }
    }
}
```

the error is :
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   CS0592  Attribute 'Table' is not valid on this declaration type. It is only valid on 'class' declarations.

What al I missing ?

Answer (score 1):

The `TableAttribute` is now resolved from `System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema` instead of it being resolved from the correct location, which is `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs`. See [TableAttribute Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.schema.tableattribute) for the faulty attribute.

For this to work, please make sure you have the correct version (4.0.5) installed for NuGet package [Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage/).

Version 5.0.0 removes the `TableAttribute`. I think it will come back in a Cosmos DB package, but haven't gotten around to finding out which one. Yet.

**EDIT:**
Using a table binding to an `IQueryable` is only supported in the Functions v1 runtime. If you are not running on the v1 runtime, you can either bind to an entire [`CloudTable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.cosmos.table.cloudtable), or to one specific item in the table by providing both partition key and row key in the binding.

Also: your POCO properties `PartitionKey` and `RowKey` hide the ones from `TableEntity`. If that's intentional, you might want to make that explicit by adding a `new` keyword.